# What is the difference between THTTPClient and TNetHTTPClient?

Tags: http, delphi

Unfortunately the documentation does not give a good definition for the components or explains the difference between them.

**THTTPClient**

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient

> Class that implements a TURLClient.
>
> TURLClient: Base class for classes that encapsulates the manager of a
>   common URL client for a specific protocol, such as THTTPClient.

**TNetHTTPClient**

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPClient

> Component to manage an HTTP client.

What is the difference between them? When should I use THTTPClient or TNetHTTPClient?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`THTTPClient` is a standalone class that is the actual HTTP implementation.

`TNetHTTPClient` is a `TComponent` wrapper for `THTTPClient` that can be dropped on a Form/Frame/DataModule at design-time.